# How to enter estimated dates in a PSQL timestamp field?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

An existing database uses a timestamp field, but sometimes the user only knows year and month of the event. How should the data be stored when only the month, day, or time is known? Keep in mind this is for appointment data, e.g. a ."time of appointment" field, but sometimes its historical in nature like "saw my lawyer, I think it was June 2019".

I'm really looking for a general solution that is language independent, likely focusing on relatively standard DB data structures for handling the limitations of a timestamp field in this regard and field types for such a common programming situation that I have named "an estimated timestamp".

It appears a timestamp field doesn't allow a date such as "2019-07-00-T00:00" which would appear to be the ideal solution if it did as it: a) maintains natural sort orders and b) provides a clear indicator its an  estimated date with adding an estimated T/F field.

What solutions have you come up with for such a situation, with the understanding this DB data is accessed by many web based front ends.

Comment: There are two questions here: 1) How to deal with data coming in with only year and month? 2) How to deal with data coming in with one of or some combination of month, day and time? You will need to provide example input data and an explanation of what the timestamp field is going to be used for? **Add as update to question**. General rule I use is to round to the minimum value the data supports e.g  `08/01/2022` for data coming in as `August 2022`.

Comment: I clarified it.

Comment: `2019-07-00-T00:00` is not a valid timestamp so no it is not suitable for a `timestamp(tz)` field.  If you want to use `timestmp(tz)` fields then the values will need to be valid timestamps. That means entering a minimum value for unknown portions of the timestamp. It also means you will probably need an additional field or fields to indicate that the timestamp is estimated and what is estimated. The other choice is to not use timestamps but a `varchar` field at which point you lose timestamp handling w/o doing a conversion, when you are back to creating an estimated timestamp.